# How to call language from database in codeigniter and call with foreach from language library message?

Tags: database, codeigniter

How can I call language id from database with print message from language library
in codeigniter

This is the image:

[image]

And I was to implement in this code and call in login form for call which language is select from database

```
<div class="form-group valid-form">
    <h4><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></h4>
    <select class="form-control" name="language" onchange="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>Language/index/'+this.value;">
        <option name="english" value="english" <?php if($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'english') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>English</option>
        <option name="french" value="french" <?php if($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'french') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>French</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("select");?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tried to figure out what you're asking, and failed - could you please show us what you expect to happen, and what's happening?

Comment: he was asking about, how he can get the languages from the database to be viewed by the user.

Comment: i am tring to fetch the languages from database table language and i have to login with that id that pass to login page from sign up from.

Comment: so you want to generate the select box from the info in the database? if so, where is your model code to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//controller

```
function function_name(){
$data=array();
$this->load->model('model_name');
$data['languageArray']=$this->model_name->get_language();
//load view file
$this->load->view('folder/file_name',$data);
}
```

//model

```
function get_language(){
return $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array();
}
```

//view

```
<select class="form-control" name="language_id" id ="language_id">
        <option value="">Select Language</option>
        <?php foreach ($languageArray as $language) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $language['id'] ?>">
         <?php echo $language['lang'] ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: if you will print $data['languageArray'] in your controller ... in this array all languages are getting

Comment: change form value by language means...? you want seleted language in select box

Comment: on select language you want insert language id or anything else?